# Pytest use variables/data in imported class

Tags: python, pytest

Let's assume I have the two following files.

**test_json.py**

```
from common import *
data = GET_JSON(URL)
class TestClass:
    import always //run the essential testcases always
    def test_valid_data(self):
        assert "IsValid" in data.json()[0], "INVALID JSON DATA"
```

**always.py**

```
import pytest
class TestAlways(): 
    def test_valid_json(self):
        assert is_json(data), "JSON is invalid"
```

I don't understand how I pass the data variable collected in test_json.py to the always.py class for it to always run the essential function of checking if the data is valid first.

Secondly, in common.py I import various modules like time, os, sys, logging. How do I share this across all files without having to always include common.py?

Sorry for these questions.. It's so confusing coming from PHP where this would work without issue.

Comment: Make `TestClass` inherit from `TestAlways`. Imports must be explicit.

Comment: What is `URL` in *test_json.py*? Is it a placeholder for a string that would change in each test file or is it a variable imported from the `common` module?